# Как правильно делать Update-операцию в репозитории для объекта с составным первичным ключом?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Приложение построено по принципу `database first`.

В базе данных есть вот такая таблица

**ExerMark**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как правильно обновлять такие объекты в репозитории**? Говоря про наш случай, то на вход я получаю `ExerMark` у которого изменилось свойство `Mark`.

Вот моя попытка:

```
public void Update(ExerMark item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    }

    var exerMark = _db.ExerMarks.Find(item); //тут возвращает null
    exerMark.Mark = item.Mark;
}
```

Как видите, у меня не получает сначала получить этот объект. А проблема конечно в том, что у меня получает большой первичный ключ.

Comment: А так нельзя обновить? https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/2.4.php

Comment: @codename0082016 я ничего не нашел по этой ссылке. Сам являюсь активным пользователя этого паблика давно.

Comment: Сделайте ключ. А на список полей ограничение уникальности. Жить станет сразу лучше. Ведь для этого и существуют суррогатные первичные ключи. Какому-то умнику показался лишним, а оно вон как обернулось.

Answer (score 0):

EF пытается получить объект по значению первичного ключа, которого, видимо, в Вашей таблице, нет. Но EF для выполнения обновления необходимо каким-то образом определить, какую именно строку в таблице нужно изменить. А т.к. первичного ключа нет, то и метод `Find()` использовать бессмысленно.  Если не можете изменить базу, то можете попробовать получать объект из таблицы по другим критериям. Например:

```
public ExerMark Update(ExerMark item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    }

    var exerMark = _db.ExerMarks.FirstOrDefault(em => em.ParticipCode == item.ParticipCode && em.ProjectCode == item.ProjectCode); 
    exerMark.Mark = item.Mark;

    _db.SaveChanges();
    return item;
}
```

Comment: PS: по-хорошему, конечно, ключ нужен. Если хотите корректно пользоваться объектно-реляционным связыванием, добавляйте ключ.